# Insert HTML code to an existing HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I add `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` to the following HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success mt-4">Select</a>
```

The desired output is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success mt-4"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Select</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried? Any attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(".btn-success").prepend("<i class="fa fa-check"></i>");
```

Note: Ideally you would set an ID in your HTML element and use `$("#yourId").prepend("<i class="fa fa-check"></i>");` to have more precise selection.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply way

```
$(".btn.btn-success").append("<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>") <-- for scape "
or
$(".btn.btn-success").append("<i class='fa fa-check'></i>")
```

This is some another way

```
let I = $("<i></i>");
$(".btn.btn-success").append(I.clone().addClass("fa fa-check"));
```

if you dont understand let me know i all help you

Answer (score 0):

You can to that like this with `prepend`:

```js
let test = () => {
  $( "a" ).prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-success mt-4" onclick="test();">Select</a>
```